# What is the name of this structure in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see in the jQuery code this structure but I don't know the name and how use correctly.

```
(function($) {
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

I suppose it's a form of past arguments to the function.

Comment: Immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: It's called a module pattern. Read all about it here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Answer (score 0):

this will execute the function immediately (immediately invoked)